# I need help making a triangle that generates using user input by making the user enter the number of rows

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-loops

It should look like this but reversed and the first column indented

```
OOOOOOO  
 OOOOOO  
  OOOOO  
   OOOO  
    OOO  
     OO  
      O
```

Every time I attempt to do it I always get this code iteration and I don't know where I am going wrong.

Here is what I got so far

```
row = int(input('Please enter how many rows you want: '))

for r in range(row,0,-1):
    for c in range(r):
        print('o', end='')
    print('')
```

Comment: please show some code!

Comment: "Should look like this...." Can't be that hard to show us what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

You can do in this way:

```
line = int(input('Please enter how many lines you want: '))
vec = [i for i in range(1,line+1)]
for elem in vec:  print("\t"+"O"*elem)
```

Output example:

[image]

Comment: join the rapidly growing club of every answer here. Shame we're not telephonic then maybe we'd know exactly what OP wants

Answer (score 0):

```
line = int(input('number of lines'))
for i in range(1, line + 1):
    a = 'O' * ((line + 1)  - i)
    b = " "*(i)
    print(b + a)
```

I don't understand what 'first column indented' means but this posts what you want I believe.

for `line = 5` 
this prints

```
 OOOOO
  OOOO
   OOO
    OO
     O
```

Unless you mean reversed as to be like this?

```
     O
    OO
   OOO
  OOOO
 OOOOO
```

In which case the code is:

```
line = int(input('number of lines'))
for i in range(line , 0, -1):
    a = 'O' * ((line + 1)  - i)
    b = " "*(i)
    print(b + a)
```

Or perhaps you mean reversed like this?

```
O
OO
OOO
OOOO
OOOOO
```

In which case, this code is your friend:

```
line = int(input('number of lines'))
for i in range(line , 0, -1):
    a = 'O' * ((line + 1)  - i)
    print(a)
```

As you can see specific questions help.

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted you so I upvote you!

Answer (score 0):

Well here goes my version of the solution

```
line = int(raw_input('Please enter how many lines you want: '))
k=''
for r in range(line):
    k=k+'0'
for r in range(line):
    print k
    k=k[0:len(k)-1]
    k=' '+k
```

The terminal output looks like this

```
Please enter how many lines you want: 7
0000000
 000000
  00000
   0000
    000
     00
      0
```

Comment: `eter` -> `enter` :-)